# Is Intel HD 3000 using 3GB shared memory normal?

Tags: windows-10, memory, intel-graphics

I'm running Windows 10 64-bit on a Lenovo G570 with an Intel Core i5-2430M and 2x4GB memory.

Recently my system has only been displaying 4GB memory on Task Manager and System, so I went to Direct X diagnostic tool and found out that my Intel HD 3000 is using 3GB as shared memory. Why I said *recently* is because a while back my OS was correctly displaying the full 8GB RAM while the shared memory was only taking 1GB. *Is this normal or not?*

I know shared memory for Intel HD is determined automatically, but I've never seen it using more than 2gigs.

My BIOS is displaying the full RAM value, 8GB, while in Windows, both on TaskMgr and System Properties, it says 4GB.

Here are two screenshots from DirectX Diagnostic Tool.

[image]
<sup>**System tab**</sup>

[image]
<sup>**Display tab**</sup>

I don't think this is BIOS issue and what I'm asking is: *Is this issue normal or not?* I need to know if this issue is the one that causing my OS memory reads problem.

Comment: What does it show for This Computer or in system properties? It shouldnt 'remove' from the system specs, it would just show it as allocated to shared. Total in task man performance should always show a full total

Comment: @Cand3r Hmm. The strange thing is My Bios is displaying 8GB while My task manager and System properties displaying 4GB. So, i think that shared memory is the one causing it. But from your explanation, Task Mgr always show full total. Its OS Issue then?

Comment: Hmmmm indeed, have you run any mem tests?

Comment: No, but i've tried to boot with my WinPE. No Prob. Shows 8GB

Answer (score 1):

Actually NVM.
The memory issue is solved now. One of my slot refused to reads the memory.
After loosing some screws a bit on Processor Cooler, its working. 
So, Right now i have 8GB.

Still, 
When The OS only reads 4GB, but with CPUZ its 8GB on single channel.
So, why CPU-Z is displaying the missing memory card when i have a slot problem? 
AND

i can't find why that shared memory for INTEL HD 3000 is huge.
With 8GB memory, INTEL HD is now displaying 5GB approx memory on DXDIAG.

So the issue didn't bother me anymore. 
Thanks.